# Overwriting config.xml for Jenkins at startup

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I am setting up Jenkins machine inside a K8S cluster and want cloud properties for my Kubernetes cluster preconfigured.

For this very reason, I want to load a customized `config.xml` file at startup.

My `config.xml` is currently inside a configMap called `jenkins-config` and contains the whole XML file with my edits.

Now with the Jenkins Image that I am using, it loads all configs under `/var/jenkins_home/`

Which means the `config.xml` file is under `/var/jenkins_home`.
`/var/jenkins_home` is being persisted of course.

I am introducing my configMap as a VolumeMount.

My deployment.yaml file is :

```
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins
        release: 1.1.1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: jenkins
          image: jenkins-master:1.0
          env:
            - name: JAVA_OPTS
              value: -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false
          ports:
            - name: http-port
              containerPort: 8080
            - name: jnlp-port
              containerPort: 54000
          volumeMounts:
            - name: jenkins-home
              mountPath: /var/jenkins_home
              readOnly: false
            - name: jenkins-config
              mountPath: /var/jenkins_home/config.xml
              subPath: config.xml
      volumes:
        - name: jenkins-home
          emptyDir: {}
        - name: jenkins-config
          configMap:
            name: jenkins-config
```

Now I can access my pod and verify that the new config is indeed there but my Jenkins is giving ERRORs like:

```
WARNING: Unable to move atomically, falling back to non-atomic move.
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /var/jenkins_home/atomic1870316694682040724tmp -> /var/jenkins_home/config.xml: Device or resource busy
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.move(UnixCopyFile.java:396)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.move(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:262)
    at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1395)
    at hudson.util.AtomicFileWriter.commit(AtomicFileWriter.java:191)
    at hudson.XmlFile.write(XmlFile.java:198)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.save(Jenkins.java:3221)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.saveQuietly(Jenkins.java:3227)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.setSecurityRealm(Jenkins.java:2505)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$16.run(Jenkins.java:3188)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1066)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Sep 15, 2018 10:06:23 PM hudson.util.AtomicFileWriter commit
INFO: The target file /var/jenkins_home/config.xml was already existing
Sep 15, 2018 10:06:23 PM hudson.util.AtomicFileWriter commit
WARNING: Unable to move /var/jenkins_home/atomic1870316694682040724tmp to /var/jenkins_home/config.xml. Attempting to delete /var/jenkins_home/atomic1870316694682040724tmp and abandoning.
Sep 15, 2018 10:06:23 PM jenkins.model.Jenkins saveQuietly
WARNING: null
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /var/jenkins_home/config.xml: Device or resource busy
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.move(UnixCopyFile.java:447)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.move(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:262)
    at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1395)
    at hudson.util.AtomicFileWriter.commit(AtomicFileWriter.java:206)
    at hudson.XmlFile.write(XmlFile.java:198)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.save(Jenkins.java:3221)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.saveQuietly(Jenkins.java:3227)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.setSecurityRealm(Jenkins.java:2505)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$16.run(Jenkins.java:3188)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1066)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /var/jenkins_home/atomic1870316694682040724tmp -> /var/jenkins_home/config.xml: Device or resource busy
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.move(UnixCopyFile.java:396)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.move(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:262)
        at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1395)
        at hudson.util.AtomicFileWriter.commit(AtomicFileWriter.java:191)
        ... 13 more
```

Looks like Jenkins loads the default `config.xml` file and then overwrites it with the one I send which makes Jenkins freak out.

I could make this part of my Docker Image BUT I want to override using K8S rather than making the file in the Image.

Any ideas on how can I safely introduce a `config.xml` file at startup in Jenkins?

**EDIT**

Another Attempt ::

I even tried the below config :

```
volumeMounts:
        - name: jenkins-home
          mountPath: /var/jenkins_home
          readOnly: false
  volumes:
    - name: jenkins-home
      configMap:
        name: jenkins-config
        items:
        - key: config.xml
          path: config.xml
```

But that yields :

```
kubectl logs -n jenkins-pipeline jenkins-bc879c4df-m8nlc
touch: cannot touch '/var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log': Read-only file system
Can not write to /var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log. Wrong volume permissions?
```

Comment: Obligatory plug for https://coderanger.net/jenkins/ which explains a much better way to do this. Rather than trying to fully control the config.xml (which Jenkins hates) use the Groovy scripting system to configure things on each startup.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically mounting `/var/jenkins_home/config.xml` on top of `/var/jenkins_home` and jenkins cannot write to it. Try this:

```
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins
        release: 1.1.1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: jenkins
          image: jenkins-master:1.0
          env:
            - name: JAVA_OPTS
              value: -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false
          ports:
            - name: http-port
              containerPort: 8080
            - name: jnlp-port
              containerPort: 54000
          volumeMounts:
          - name: jenkins-home
            mountPath: /etc/config
      volumes:
        - name: jenkins-home
          hostPath:
            # directory location on host
            path: /data
            # this field is optional
            type: Directory
          configMap:
            name: jenkins-config
            items:
            - key: config
              path: config.xml
```

Comment: Thanks. But this implementation leads to `touch: cannot touch '/var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log': Read-only file system
Can not write to /var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log. Wrong volume permissions?` . I even added `readOnly: false` to VolumeMounts but same ERROR. Ive updated my main Question with this too.

Comment: Try configuring the volume as hostPath so that Jenkins can write to it. But remember that you may have to constrain your pod to this specific node, otherwise your config will change if the pod starts on a different node. The alternative is remote volumes. More about volume [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/)